# Android Socket getting exception while sending data

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have tested the code below. It was working in emulator but not working in Android Mobile. Do I need to do any settings? Please help me.
Thank you.

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.54", 9083);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    out.println("Testing");

    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    String readObject = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(readObject);
} 
 catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: sometimes there could be a problem with ip/address

Comment: check if logcat is saying anything strange

Comment: No, there is nothing in logcat. but i got exception in my catch block "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer"

Comment: May be something wrong with your wifi.

Comment: what other testing have you done? Does your app request the correct permissions? Have you verified that the phone is connected to the network? Have you verified that the server you are trying to connect to is working correctly?

Comment: The issue is there is no sim in the phone. If i put the sim and test again everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset by peer" means that someone between your phone and the server (inclusive) closed the connection while you were reading it.

First check if the server receives and sends anything. If not, then someone between your phone and the server is blocking the transfer. If you are on corporate WiFi, there may be firewalls prrotecting the server etc. If on 3G there definitely is one.

You should add the stack trace to your post. Without it our answers are just guesswork...

Edit: The IP address 192.168.x.x points to an internal network. Are you sure you can access the internal network from WiFi/3G?

Comment: -1. It doesn't mean that. It means that someone *reset* the connection. Just closing it would cause the end of stream condition.

Comment: Resetting a connection does mean exactly that. Reset just does not involve the handshakes that are preformed when the connection is closed controllably. Firewalls are known to use reset instead of close when blocking traffic because it reduces traffic when dealing with unwanted connections.

Comment: Reset and close are two different operations. If you meant reset you should have said so in your answer.

Comment: Ignoring the gratuitous offensiveness, your post conflates an important difference, and doing so prevents people from understanding. The term 'close' in my post *means* close. If the peer closes and then receives data it will issue an RST. That's the major cause of 'connection reset by peer'. What you have written here simply isn't.

Answer (score 0):

'Connection reset by peer' is usually caused by writing to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error. It doesn't show up on that write, but on a subsequent I/O operation.